# How to preserve csv cell format without convert it to scientific notation in c#?

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to create a csv and add some fields and then send it via email. But, some fields are automatically converted into scientific notation. Like, When below csv is opened it shows ID as exponential (like 938100000010025 is shown as 9.38E+14).

Code:

```
private async Task SendDetailsCsvToEmail(Entity entity, SessionContext context)
{
   
    var csvContent = new StringBuilder();
    csvContent.AppendLine("Name, Id, Address");
    csvContent.AppendLine($"{entity.Name},{entity.Id},{entity.Address}");

    var csvBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent.ToString());
    //Call function to send csv in mail
}
```

I applied `\"=\"\"{entity.Id}\"\"` , but it did not work

Comment: I assume you mean "when opened in Excel".  That's where the problem is.   The final expression you show is missing a double quote.  It needs to end with three.  Alternatively, put an "x" in front the the number to force it to be interpreted as a string.

Comment: Open with notepad you will not see the scientific numbers.  Instead of double clicking on the csv file if you open excel and import you can set the column types.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text